# Why are both the 'else' and 'if' statements running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

While posting this question, I've already checked the other links that have similar titles. All of those either don't have an answer to my question, or don't apply to this piece of code. For example, the link here:
[Why is my batch script running both if and else statement when if statement matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554038/why-is-my-batch-script-running-both-if-and-else-statement-when-if-statement-matc)
says that it's because the OP used `echo` in the script. Here, I don't use it but I still get the result of both the `if` and the `else`.

```
while True:
    selection = input("Type a command or use a page selection")
    if selection in ('exit','quit'):
        sys.exit()
    if selection in ('page 1','1'):
        print("Page 1 text here")
    if selection in ('page 2','2'):
        print("Page 2 text here")
    else:
        print("Invalid command or page number")
```

Comment: Which `if` are you referring to (there are three separate `if`s in your code)? What is the input data you use, what do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: I copy/pasted into python, entered 2 and it only printed "Page 2 text here" and then looped back to top. Seem to work fine.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, yes but if you type `1`, it will give you page 1 and the message "Invalid command and page number".

Comment: true, that's how it's written. I suppose OP meant to use elif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is one long conditional - you have to use elif in the middle:

```py
if 1:
    a()
elif 2:
    b()
elif 3:
    c()
else:
    d()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to use [`if-elif-else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) in these kind of situations:

```
while True:
    selection = input("Type a command or use a page selection")
    if selection in ('exit','quit'):
        sys.exit()
    elif selection in ('page 1','1'):
        print("Page 1 text here")
    elif selection in ('page 2','2'):
        print("Page 2 text here")
    else:
        print("Invalid command or page number")
```

Answer (score 1):

To run only one if statement in a series of them you must have and else if statement, elif, everythime you put if, it is considered with the other if/elif/else statements. Your else statement is independent of the first two if statements, I fixed it below.

```
while True:
    selection = input("Type a command or use a page selection: ")
    if selection in ('exit','quit'):
        sys.exit()
    elif selection in ('page 1','1'):
        print("Page 1 text here")
    elif selection in ('page 2','2'):
        print("Page 2 text here")
    else:
        print("Invalid command or page number")
```